# How to update only one sheet from the Excel file using pandas

Tags: excel, pandas

i have One 1.excel file that contain
sheet_1, shee_2 and sheet_3

and i have another 2.excel file that contain sheet_2

and i want to update replace 2.excel sheet_2 file into 1.excel file sheet_2

and i try with

```
finaldest = '1.xlsx'
REPORT2WRITERFINAL = pd.ExcelWriter(finaldest)

path = '1.xlsx'
x0 = pd.ExcelFile(path, engine='openpyxl')

path2 = '2.xlsx'
x1 = pd.ExcelFile(path2, engine='openpyxl')

for sheet in x0.sheet_names:
    if sheet in x1.sheet_names:
        t0 = x1.parse(sheet, header=0)
        t0.to_excel(REPORT2WRITERFINAL, startrow=0, startcol=1, sheet_name=sheet, index=False)

REPORT2WRITERFINAL.save()

REPORT2WRITERFINAL.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `ExcelWriter` in append mode with replace sheet strategy:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('1.xlsx', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace') as x0, \
     pd.ExcelFile('2.xlsx') as x1:

    for sheet in set(x0.book.sheetnames).intersection(x1.book.sheetnames):
        df = x1.parse(sheet, header=0)
        df.to_excel(x0, sheet, startrow=0, startcol=1, index=False)
```

Comment: Finally someone showed how to use the if_sheet_exist parameter.